# Get the AbstractClass of a model

Tags: django, django-models

how could i get the AbstractClass of a Model in Django?
I tried to do it with type but type gives me the BaseModel class of django or the type of the model itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
def go_for_the_bases(model):
    while hasattr(model, '_meta'):
        model = model.__base__
        if hasattr(model, '_meta') and model._meta.abstract == True:
            yield model
```

Answer (score 1):

You can user mro() which stands for Method Resolution Order.

```
ClassName.mro()
```

which gives the tuple of the class, its base, its base's base, ...., and so on till we reach object.

You can loop over it and check for className._meta.abstract is True till you reach the abstract class.